# elm: validation attributes are ignored

Tags: validation, twitter-bootstrap-3, elm

I have a form and i want to add some validation attributes to a input of type text. Here is my elm code for the view:

```
Html.form [ attribute "data-toggle" "validator", attribute "role" "form" ]
    [ div [ id "global" ]
        [ div [ class "container" ]
            [ div [ class "form-group" ]
                [ label [ class "control-label", for "sss" ] [ text "dummy text here" ]
                , div []
                    [ input [ class "form-control", id "sss", placeholder "text", type_ "text", pattern ".{1,}", required True, onInput ChangeMessage]
                        []
                    ]
                ]
....
```

And here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>test title</title>
        <script src="Main.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>

    <body>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.4.5/js/bootstrapvalidator.min.js'></script>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <img src="./logo.svg" width="165" height="95" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container text-center">
          <h2>big title</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </body>

    <script>
        var app = Elm.Main.fullscreen();
    </script>
</html>
```

But the validators are ignored. If I click on this input and click on something else, I'm not seeing any error or the input margins turning red, so how can I validate that in this input I have at least one character?

Comment: As far as I can remember Bootstrap 3 does not offer anything for form validation. If you are using [1000hz/bootstrap-validator](https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator) then you are probably missing the import in your HTML.

Comment: @halfzebra I've updated the html but still not working... you can see the updated html here

Comment: Unfortunately, you will not be able to use this library since it mutates the DOM tree produced by your Elm application. Check out the example I have made for [Select 2 integration with Elm](https://github.com/halfzebra/elm-examples/tree/master/examples/select2-integration) it might give you the idea on how you can proceed.

Comment: So if I cannot use bootstrap validators, this means that in the view I have to use an if statement to check my data? and based on my conditions I show the input with a class or another?

Comment: You can not use any library, which makes changes to the elements produced by Elm. There are multiple ways you could tackle this task in Elm, I would recommend asking that question on Slack or [r/elm](https://www.reddit.com/r/elm/), because it is way too broad for SO.

Comment: @Buda Gavril, that's correct. You should have a condition in your view to add a class depending on the state of your data.